# Split multiple points in text format and switch coordinates in postgres column

Tags: sql, postgresql, replace

I have a PostgreSQL column of type text that contains data like shown below

```
(32.85563, -117.25624)(32.855470000000004, -117.25648000000001)(32.85567, -117.25710000000001)(32.85544, -117.2556)
(37.75363, -121.44142000000001)(37.75292, -121.4414)
```

I want to convert this into another column of type text like shown below

```
(-117.25624, 32.85563)(-117.25648000000001,32.855470000000004 )(-117.25710000000001,32.85567 )(-117.2556,32.85544 )
(-121.44142000000001,37.75363 )(-121.4414,37.75292 )
```

As you can see, the values inside the parentheses have switched around. Also note that I have shown two records here to indicate that not all fields have same number of parenthesized figures.

**What I've tried**
I tried extracting the column to Java and performing my operations there. But due to sheer amount of records I have, I will run out of memory. I also cannot do this method in batched due to time constraints.

**What I want**
A SQL query or a sequence of SQL queries that will achieve the result that I have mentioned above.

I am using PostgreSQL9.4 with PGAdmin III as the client

Comment: Are each parentheses value it's own row or are there many values in one row as the formatting of the question suggests? And are the parentheses part of the value?

Comment: @jpw Its a text field. So the entire row that you see, including the parantheses, is part of the value. Also note that I have shown two records here to indicate that not all fields have same number of paranthesized figures.

Comment: Is there a specific use case around storing these values as a text column of lists? IMO, it is better you use a programming language for such tasks. I am not sure why you would run out of memory for such a task.

Comment: While this most likely is possible to solve using the regular expression functions in Postgresql I would focus on normalizing the data so that there won't be more than on value stored in any column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I put in the question, *I tried extracting the column to Java and performing my operations there. But due to sheer amount of records I have, I will run out of memory. I also cannot do this method in batched due to time constraints.*

I ran out of memory here as I was putting everything in a Hashmap of
 **< my_primary_key,the_newly_formatted_text >**. As the text was very long sometimes and due to the sheer number of records that I had, it wasnt surprising that I got an OOM.

**Solution that I used:**
As suggested my many folks here, this solution was better solved with a code. I wrote a small script that formatted the text as per my liking and wrote the primary key and the newly formatted text to a file in tsv format. Then I imported the tsv in  a new table and updated the original table from the new one.

Answer (score 1):

this is a type of problem that should not be solved by sql, but you are lucky to use Postgres.

I suggest the following steps in defining your algorithm.

First part will be turning your strings into a structured data, second will transform structured data back to string in a format that you require.

**From string to data**

First, you need to turn your bracketed values into an array, which can be done with `string_to_array` function.

Now you can turn this array into rows with `unnest` function, which will return a row per bracketed value.

Finally you need to slit values in each row into two fields.

**From data to string**

You need to group results of the first query with results wrapped in `string_agg` function that will combine all numbers in rows into string.

You will need to experiment with brackets to achieve exactly what you want.

**PS**. I am not providing query here. Once you have some code that you tried, let me know.

Comment: Let me try that and get back to you. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you also have a PK or some unique column, and possibly other columns, you can do as follows:

```
SELECT id, (...), string_agg(point(pt[1], pt[0])::text, '') AS col_reversed
FROM (
  SELECT id, (...), unnest(string_to_array(replace(col, ')(', ');('), ';'))::point AS pt
  FROM my_table) sub
GROUP BY id; -- assuming id is PK or no other columns
```

PostgreSQL has the `point` type which you can use here. First you need to make sure you can properly divide the long string into individual points (insert ';' between the parentheses), then turn that into an array of individual points in text format, unnest the array into individual rows, and finally cast those rows to the `point` data type:

```
unnest(string_to_array(replace(col, ')(', ');('), ';'))::point AS pt
```

You can then create a new point from the point you just created, but with the coordinates reversed, turn that into a string and aggregate into your desired output:

```
string_agg(point(pt[1], pt[0])::text, '') AS col_reversed
```

But you might also move away from the text format and make an array of `point` values as that will be easier and faster to work with:

```
array_agg(point(pt[1], pt[0])) AS pt_reversed
```